# Parsing with strings into different types with different delimiters

Tags: c++, string, parsing, vector

This is actually the first time I have used this website: usually I am able to find the a solution from a previous post, but this time I am to no avail. Anyways, my problem is that I am trying to parse a file that contains commas and parentheses. It also contains strings and doubles that I need to change from the string into a double so I can use the data. I made a struct to store the data.

```
struct Artery{
string segment; string name;
double length; double radius; double wall_thickness;
double young_modulus; double compliance;

Artery(string seg, string n, double l, double r, double w, double y, double c)
    : segment(seg), name(n), length(l), radius(r), wall_thickness(w), young_modulus(y), compliance(c){}
};
```

The data will be in the format as follows:

(Segment, Name, Length, Radius, Wall Thickness, Young's Modulus, Compliance)
(2A, Aorta_Ascendens, 2, 1.47, .164, 4, 53.4)
(2B, Aorta_Ascendens, 2, 1.44, .161, 4, 51.0)
(3A, Arcus_Aorta, 2, 1.12, .132, 4, 29.6)

I'm really just a beginner into the C++ language (taking a college course on the subject right now actually) and we haven't covered low-level programming with pointers and such that I know is what is usually used to parse this kind of thing. Could I get some help with this? I really don't have any idea on how to get this working.

Below is what I currently have in the process of attempting to parse the file. I wanted to eventually at the end have a vector of Artery that will serve as the basis for me accessing the information.

```
void read_data(vector<Artery>& v, ifstream& ifs){
//reads and seperates file for arterial data (currently from the westerhoff model)
vector<string> data_string;
while (!ifs.eof){
    string data_set = " ";
    getline(ifs, data_set);
    data_string.push_back(data_set);
}

for (int i = 0; i < data_string.size(); ++i){
    string seg; string n;
    double l; double r; double w; double y; double c;

    istringstream iss(data_string[i]);




}

}
```

To recap: I need help with parsing the file with the above format and then convert that format into an Artery. I want to then compile them into a vector of Artery to later have access to them.

Thank you,

Zav

Comment: Are commas part of the example strings? That is to say, is your data comma-separated-values (CSV)? And, are the parentheses begin and end each line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There are many ways to do this.**

Assuming your filestream, `ifs` is already initialized and `is_open` (that is you've already done the checking of the stream, then you do all operations in one go (reducing your runtime by at least a factor of two compared to your version):

```
void read_data(std::vector<Artery>& v, std::ifstream ifs) {
    std::vector<std::string> data_strings;

    std::string temp;

    //read the file by lines
    while(std::getline(ifs, temp)) {
        //store the line (included for completeness)
        data_strings.push_back(temp);

        //as you didn't state if your lines began and ended with parentheses
        //I opted to cover removal of them:
        size_t begin = temp.find("(");//as there is only 1
        size_t end = temp.find(")");//as there is only 1

        temp = temp.substr(begin+1, end-1);

        std::istringstream iss(temp);
        Artery artery;

        int col = 1;//the current column

        //here we're going to use the stringstream to tokenize the string by commas
        //using std::getline
        while (std::getline(iss, temp, ',')) {
            std::istringstream is(temp);//this is another string stream initialized to the token (which may or may not be a string)
            //determine which artery property to modify based on the column number
            switch(col) {
                case 1:
                    is >> artery.segment;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    is >> artery.name;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    is >> artery.length;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    is >> artery.radius;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    is >> artery.wall_thickness;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    is >> artery.young_modulus;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    is >> artery.compliance;
                    break;
                default:
                    std::cerr << "Invalid column!\n";
            }
            ++col;
        }

        //now the artery has been correctly initialized, we can store it:
        v.push_back(artery);
    }
}
```

You'll notice that this version doesn't utilize the `Artery` Constructor that you supplied. It could have been used, but from how you've defined `Artery`, it highly resembles a POD (Plain-Old-Data type); hence, I've treated it in this solution.

Also, as you I wasn't sure if parentheses were part of each constituent line, I've treated them accordingly by removing them. (Of course, if your data doesn't contain these, you can remove the code that handles that deletion, easily).

NOTE:

**My use of the stringstream extraction operator (`>>`) doesn't check for proper assignment.** But, as this is a naive example, that is something you can do for yourself.